# import S3 from s3 library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I installed s3 library on my python 3.8 environment using

`pip install s3`

which installed s3 version `3.0.0`

I then try to run

`from s3 import S3`

But I would get an error of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 1, in <module>
    from s3 import S3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/s3/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .s3 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/s3/s3.py", line 253
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It looks like the library is written with python 2 syntax.  Is there a way to get this fixed?  I would like to use the s3 library in my python 3.8 environment.

Answer (score 2):

Use boto3 instead of s3. It is the official amazon library that is compatible with python3 - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-examples.html.

FYI, s3 is an opensource contribution project and it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore with the [last release in 2015](https://pypi.org/project/s3/), probably should never be using it.